# Emacs: globally enable whitespace-mode

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I want globally enable whitespace-mode. I have tried this in my .emacs:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq-default whitespace-style '(face trailing lines empty indentation::space))
(setq-default whitespace-line-column 80)
(setq global-whitespace-mode 1)
(whitespace-mode 1)
```

but without success... I able to enable it via M+x whitespace-mode, but I want it to enable it globally... Any suggestions? I am using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 .

Comment: Note that `whitespace-mode` and `global-whitespace-mode` are different minor modes. The former is buffer-local, the latter is not. If the buffer-local mode is enabled for a given buffer, the global mode will not have any effect on that buffer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In general it's best to enable/disable modes by using the function call, not setting the variable (which is what you did for `global-whitespace-mode`).

Try:

```
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

Comment: It's both. See `C-h v global-whitespace-mode RET` and `C-h f global-whitespace-mode RET`

Comment: phils, Thanks, quite surprising for me... I definitely have to learn some elisp to customize emacs :)

Comment: @phils - How do I get to the correct mode to type 'C-h v global-whitespace-mode RET'?  I've spent 3 hours looking in documents, tutorials, and online.  I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: On a Mac, it's option M to get to Mark Set and then option M-x.  :-)

Comment: How would you disable it? With 0, -1 ?

Comment: @DidierA. You can disable it with a `-1` - which is mentioned in the documentation, which you can see with `C-h f global-whitespace-mode`