# Emacs show invisible symbols (\n)

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to highlight several invisible symbols in Emacs, specifically `\n`. I am trying the following:

```
(standard-display-ascii ?\n "¬\n")
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("¬" . font-lock-comment-face)))
```

Unfortunately, it looks like only typed explicitly symbols will use the specified font-face. Is there a proper way to highlight the display-ascii symbol?

One more related question: replacing `nil` with `'lisp-interaction-mode` in the second expression makes it not working anymore. Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378831/emacs-globally-enable-whitespace-mode

Comment: whitespace-mode only highlights white spaces as far as I know.

Comment: This [page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WhiteSpace) seems to indicate that there's a minor mode for newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Highlighting newline chars is trivial using the library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight-chars.el):

   ```
   M-x hc-highlight-chars C-q C-j RET font-lock-comment-face RET
   ```

   You are prompted for the chars to highlight -- hit `C-q C-j` (inserts a newline char), then hit `RET` to enter the list of chars you inserted (just a newline char here).

   You are then prompted for the face to use to highlight those chars (in this case, just one char, newline) -- type `font-lock-comment-face` or whatever other face name you like.

   See description of the library [*here*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowWhiteSpace#toc2).
2. And if you want to also change the display to show (the highlighted char) ¬, then just do also what you already tried:

   ```
   M-: (standard-display-ascii ?\n "¬\n")
   ```

The result of #1 + #2 is highlighted `¬` in place of the usual newline display.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why my initial attempt didn't work well? Why `font-lock-add-keywords` doesn't play well with `standard-display-ascii`?

Comment: No, I don't really know.  Perhaps someone will explain it well. But you have a solution anyway, right? ;-)

Comment: I do :) I ended up going with my solution because it doesn't require any additional extensions and seems to work fine. Although I have this terrible feeling when I don't understand why something doesn't work — I feel like if I find more issues with this I will not be able to fix them because I don't know how it works already.

Comment: Then I don't understand your original question/problem.  You said that it does *not* work, AFAICT.  And evaluating your two sexps alone in fact does not work, AFAICT -- the "display ascii symbol" is not highlighted, just as you stated.  I thought that was your problem.  Just what is your problem, for which you are "going with your solution"?  And what is your solution to it? You should *post your solution clearly as an answer*.  And accept it if it is the solution you prefer.  It's about helping others and making things clear.

Comment: I have posted my solution as an answer. I can't accept it yet. I will modify it if it's not clear enough.

Comment: Dunno why, but I didn't notice that that answer was from you. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: You solution seems to perform better. Although I have an issue with it. First, I could add it to my config: `(hc-highlight-chars ?\n 'whitespace-newline)` — am I doing this right? I am getting an error. Second, for some reason the newline symbol in the code comments gets comment's face. I thought hc-highlight-chars would override that?

Comment: 1. The first arg to `hc-highlight-chars` is a *list* of a *string* of chars, not a char -- e.g., `("\n")` -- see the doc string.  (I just clarified the doc string a little; see the latest version)  So, for example, `(hc-highlight-chars '("\n") 'whitespace-newline)` 2. See option `hc-other-chars-font-lock-override` for interaction with other font-locking -- you want `t` as value.  In general, see the doc.

Answer (score 15):

I just booted up emacs, did the command `M-x`, and typed

```
whitespace-mode
```

Afterwards I got a `$` indicator for newlines.

Answer (score 6):

To only show newlines the following can be used:

`(global-whitespace-newline-mode)`

or an alternative:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face newline-mark))
(whitespace-mode t)
```

And to use the custom symbol `¬` for it:

```
(setq whitespace-display-mappings
      '((newline-mark 10 [172 10])))
```

Then the `whitespace-newline` font-lock can be used to customize the style.

**Edit:**

For some reason placing this customization in `.emacs` config results in faces styles not applying to the symbol, I am not sure why (would be great if somebody could explain this). Using hooks works fine:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (lambda () 
            (whitespace-newline-mode t)))
```

Comment: Here are some settings you can use to customize whitespace-mode:  lines lines-tail newline trailing space-before-tab space-after-tab empty indentation-space indentation indentation-tab tabs spaces.  And, here is an example of just spaces, tabs and end of lines:  `(setq whitespace-style '(face space-mark tab-mark newline-mark) )`  I don't use global modes, and instead prefer mode hooks and `(whitespace-mode t)`

Comment: `(global-whitespace-newline-mode)` placed in `.emacs` is finicky for some reason, it enables the newline-mode globally and for all symbols. When I run it manually everything is fine. I tried your advice and it works much better. What does `face` mean in that list? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: `M-x describe-variable RET whitespace-style`:  *. . . face -- enable all visualization via faces (see below). . . .*

Comment: Thanks you. Regarding the hooks usage. Do you explicitly state which modes you want the whiteline to be enabled for? I would imagine it's tedious to add each mode to the list once you pick up a new language. Or is there some trick to make it easier?

Comment: I have a list of mode-hooks that I regularly use and add or subtract the desired options as needed -- e.g., `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda () (whitespace-mode t) (linum-mode 1) (hl-line-mode 1) . . .))`.  Alternatively, you can have a global mode / function and insert conditions -- e.g., `(when (eq major-mode 'c-mode) . . .`  There are other ways, but those are the most common that I use regularly.  You could even wrap your common ones into a function -- e.g., `(defun my-favorite-minor-modes () (whitespace-mode t) (linum-mode 1) (hl-line-mode 1))` and put that function inside a mode hook.

Comment: I have played with this all a little bit more and it seems like emacs doesn't pick custom faces styles when `(global-whitespace-newline-mode)` is placed in `.emacs`. Only if I call this manually after emacs starts. Where the problem could be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52451/discussion-between-egdmitry-and-lawlist)